AWS Textract With AWS Signature Version 4 Using Go Lang
I have 3 credentials:

host
acckey
secretkey

That from AWS. I am using AWS Signature Ver 4 method
And then i want to using textract feature from AWS with Golang. I have build the code and have a problem:
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. 

This is my code
main.go:
Note: Upload image with base64 string
func (server *Server) extraction(ctx *gin.Context) {
    var req extractionRequest
    if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&req); err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, errorResponse(err))
        return
    }

    data, err := json.Marshal(req)
        if err != nil {
            ctx.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Unable to marshal JSON"})
            return
    }

    reqToAmazon, err := http.NewRequest("POST", endpoint+apiPath, bytes.NewBuffer(data))
        if err != nil {
            ctx.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Unable to create request"})
            return
    }

    reqToAmazon.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    reqToAmazon.Header.Set("X-Amz-Date", time.Now().UTC().Format("20060102T150405Z"))
    err = util.Sign(reqToAmazon, region, service, secretKey, accessKey, data)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": fmt.Sprintf("Failed to sign request: %v", err)})
        return
    }
    client := http.Client{}
    fmt.Println(reqToAmazon.WithContext(ctx))
    resp, err := client.Do(reqToAmazon.WithContext(ctx))
    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Unable to send request"})
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Unable to read response"})
        return
    }

    responsed:= gin.H{
        "reqToAmazon": gin.H{
            "method":  reqToAmazon.Method,
            "url":     reqToAmazon.URL.String(),
            "headers": reqToAmazon.Header,
        },
        "responseFromAmazon": json.RawMessage(body),
    }

    ctx.JSON(http.StatusCreated, responsed)
}

textract.go as a util:
// AWS Signature Version 4
func Sign(req *http.Request, region, service, secretKey, accessKey string, documentContent []byte) error {
    t := time.Now().UTC()
    dateStamp := t.Format("20060102")
    amzDate := t.Format("20060102T150405Z")
    credentialScope := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s/%s/aws4_request", dateStamp, region, service)

    type RequestBody struct {
        DocumentContent string `json:"DocumentContent"`
    }
    requestBody := RequestBody{
        DocumentContent: string(documentContent),
    }

    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(requestBody)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal documentContent to JSON: %v", err)
    }

    var payloadHash string
    if len(jsonData) > 0 {
        hash := sha256.Sum256(jsonData)
        payloadHash = hex.EncodeToString(hash[:])
    } else {
        hash := sha256.Sum256([]byte(""))
        payloadHash = hex.EncodeToString(hash[:])
    }

    if req.Host == "" {
        req.Host = req.URL.Host
    }

    httpMethod := req.Method
    canonicalURI := req.URL.Path
    canonicalQueryString := req.URL.RawQuery
    canonicalHeaders := 
        "content-type:" + req.Header.Get("Content-Type") + "\n" +
        "host:" + req.Host + "\n" +
        "x-amz-date:" + amzDate + "\n"
    signedHeaders := "content-type;host;x-amz-date"

    canonicalRequest := strings.Join([]string{
        httpMethod,
        canonicalURI,
        canonicalQueryString,
        canonicalHeaders,
        signedHeaders,
        payloadHash,
    }, "\n")

    hash := sha256.New()
    hash.Write([]byte(canonicalRequest))
    hashedCanonicalRequest := hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil))

    stringToSign := strings.Join([]string{
        "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256",
        amzDate,
        credentialScope,
        hashedCanonicalRequest,
    }, "\n")


    signingKey := getSignatureKey(secretKey, dateStamp, region, service)
    signature := hmacSHA256(signingKey, []byte(stringToSign))
    authHeader := fmt.Sprintf("AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=%s/%s, SignedHeaders=%s, Signature=%s",accessKey, credentialScope, signedHeaders, hex.EncodeToString(signature))

    req.Header.Set("Authorization", authHeader)

    return nil
}

func getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, region, service string) []byte {
    kDate := hmacSHA256([]byte("AWS4"+key), []byte(dateStamp))
    kRegion := hmacSHA256(kDate, []byte(region))
    kService := hmacSHA256(kRegion, []byte(service))
    kSigning := hmacSHA256(kService, []byte("aws4_request"))
    return kSigning
}

func hmacSHA256(key, data []byte) []byte {
    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, key)
    h.Write(data)
    return h.Sum(nil)
}

In this util contain the process of get the athorization header
FINISHED:
JUST CHECK YOUR BASE64 FILE
